# Grow bitmask border without touching objects

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision

I've written a bitmask filter in C#, to grow a border, where found pixels should grow border if there is enough space, but the areas may not touch each other

```
input mask   output mask
..........    .....xxx...
.....x....    .....xxxx...
.....x....    xxx..xxxxxx.
..x..xxxx.    xxx..xxxxxx.
..........    xxx..xxxxxx.
```

Using a 5x5 binary convolution that checks the border.
The border consists of 8 pixels `(x-2,y-2)`, `(x,y-2)`, `(x+2,y-2)`... i.e. corners and centers of borders.
If a pixel is found, I set its corresponding array `P[i]` to `true`.
So these 8 pixels are represented in a boolean array starting from `P[0]` trough `p[7]`.

Next I count boolean `true`s.

If the count of `P[.] > 3` then there is another object nearby and I don't grow the border there.

If the count is 1, so if for example `(x-2,y)==true` then write mask `(x-1,y)`.

If the count is 2, so if for example `(x+2,y)==true && (x+2,y+2)==true` then write mask `(x+1,y+1)`.

I've got quite a lot of boolean comparisons to eventually make this work.
I won't bore you width the dull code, but I'm wondering if the principle I use is ideal for this, or if there exists other methods to do this.

As I got a side effect (though not really a problem) that makes the shapes more cubic over every iteration. Which seems to happen less in programs such as PhotoShop.

=====
some additional info, the code had to run on a video stream, so i prefer fast ways. I wrote "dull" code,  if i would print this its 80+ lines most is binary compare code and switch cases too make it fast, 80+ is a to long post for here, much easier to understand when explained in normal language.

Comment: I changed your text "binary convulsion" to "binary convolution", which is what I think you wanted to write. However, I don't know what a binary convolution is. It seems you implemented a custom binary filter that works in a 5x5 neighborhood.

Comment: ha yes thanks, i'm not an Englishman.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of mathematical morphology? You more or less implemented a [thickening operator](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thick.htm) (though thickening is defined differently, I think the result is more or less similar), but there are more efficient ways to do the same thing.

One alternative approach is to:

- Compute the [distance transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) of the inverse of your image. This is an image where the further away from your objects you get, the larger the grey value is. This image will have ridges exactly half-way between the objects. Let's call this image `distance`.
- Compute the [watershed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)) of `distance`. This is a binary image with lines that run along the ridges of `distance`. Let's call this `separation`.
- [Threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) `distance` at the appropriate value to get objects grown by the amount you want them grown. If you want to grow objects by 10 pixels, threshold such that all pixels with a value less or equal to 10 are selected (`true`).
- Subtract `separation` from `distance`. The pixels in `distance` that are set, and also set in `separation`, should be reset. You now have your original objects grown by your chosen distance, but still separate.

I won't bore you width the dull code...

Comment: i dont think those fit his requirement, he wrote that he would like the shapes to grow but only if there is enough space as they should not get connected. Thats an interesting problem though. I kinda wonder if a cellular automata could do it or not.

Comment: @user613326 That is exactly what this suggestion does. The shapes grow until they almost touch, but remain separate. I'm sure you could device a cellular automata to do this, but it wouldn't be nearly as efficient as the algorithm I outline. Cellular automata have been more or less abandoned in image processing somewhere in the 1980's.

Comment: Oh ah now isee , the dots where steps.   ;)  
Thought you gave a several answers there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo hm i kinda doubt that would be more efficient, as i'm building this way around objects i can skip large areas. I'm not sure though, but my method can keep up with a video feed. width not to exotic hardware, maybe I should test it out

Comment: @user3800527: It depends on how far you want to grow your objects. You need to make a pass through the image for each pixel growth. The distance transform and the watershed each do two passes through the image. The threshold and the subtraction can be combined into a fifth pass.

Comment: hmm distance is a bit more passes in itself, but maybe there is a shortcut possible no need to watershed, if distance from all directions < then border.. size, while wider area should lower then some seize as in my current filter.

Comment: @user613326, you mentioned cellular automata, any particular one ?.

Comment: @user3800527: Come to think of it, you can combine all these steps into one. It's more or less what [`dip::GrowRegions`](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__regions.html#ga47164db172b086fad8a879434516d4a9) in DIPlib 3 does. You could modify that algorithm to output a binary image instead, and leave a one-pixel gap, by looking at how `dip::Watershed` with the "correct" flag does that. `dip::GrowRegions` requires a labeled image. Running `dip::Label` and `dip::GrowRegions` takes 1/40th of a second for an image of 1280x768 pixels, all on one core.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for the tip, though i'm not sure i'm allowed to use their code (I dont have Mathlab, and i'm not sure about their license)

Comment: @user3800527: DIPlib 3 is C++ with a permissive open-source license (Apache). DIPlib 2 is close-sourced, that wouldn't be useful to you.